# Issues pulling back values while web scraping a table

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I am attempting to pull the text from a table on a webpage. I pull the webpage using Invoke-WebRequest, set that variable to show "AllElements" and attempt to only pull the inner values matching "Table"; but when I run the script nothing is pulled back and no errors are shown.

```
$URI = 'https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/'

$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI

$R.AllElements|?{$_.Class -eq "table"}|select innerText
```

I was hoping to show the values of the table on the python.org site, but when the script is run nothing is returned.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is because there are no tables or table class, it's a div with dynamically generated ordered list items.
You can see this in the browser developer tools, using F12 in Edge or similar in Firefox, Chrome, etc...

```
$URI = 'https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716'

$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URI

$R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.Class -eq 'container' }


$R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.Class -eq 'list-row-container menu' }


($R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.class -eq 'list-row-container menu'}).innerText


($R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.Class -eq 'release-number' })


($R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.Class -eq 'release-number' }).outerHTML


(($R.AllElements | 
Where {$_.Class -eq 'release-number' }).outerHTML -split '<a href="|/">Python')[2]
```

Or just do this...

```
$R.Links
$R.Links.href
$R.Links.href -match 'downloads'
```